# ios7: UILabel with newline as first character let's whole text disappear

Tags: ios7, uilabel, newline, multiline

If you have a UILabel with numberOfLines set something > 1 and try the follwoing:

```
UILabel *lbl;
lbl.text = "line1\nline2";   // works and displays 2 lines
```

> line1
>
> line2

```
lbl.text = "\nline2"; // works in iOS 6 and shows an empty line and a second line with line2
```

does not show anything in iOS 7

Under iOS6 you get:
>
>

> line2  (with an empty first line)

Any idea why a newline character at the beginning of a Label-text spoils the UILabel since iOS 7?

Comment: Are you sure the frame of the UILabel is being calculated correctly? It could be that the content is being drawn outside of the labels bounds so you can't see it.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and how I fixed it ??
I added a blank space before new line character i.e "\n" like @" \n hi this is sample code."
and it worked fine then.
Try it Plzz.

Comment: Well .. It does seem to do the job..! +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to add this:

```
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
```

to enable multiline. It works differently on 6 and 7 ios.